# Show that any commutative group of finite order is finitely generated $\mathbb{Z} $-module .

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, modules, finitely-generated

> Show that any commutative group of finite order is finitely generated  $\mathbb{Z} $-module .

I see that  any commutative group is $\mathbb{Z} $-module. But why is any finite group finitely generated?

Comment: Well, what finite set might you use as generators?

Comment: After you ask a question here, if you get an acceptable answer, you should "accept" the answer by clicking the check mark $\checkmark$ next to it. This scores points for you and for the person who answered your question. You can find out more about accepting answers here: [How do I accept an answer?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/), [Why should we accept answers?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3399/), [What should I do if someone answers my question?](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 0):

> But why is any finite group finitely generated?

Let $(G, \circ)$ be a finite group. Then $G=\{g_1, g_2, \dots, g_{\lvert G\rvert}\}$ for some $g_i$ because $G$ is finite, where $\lvert G\rvert$ is the order of the group. Every element of $(G, \circ)$ can be written as a product of elements in $G$ with respect to $\circ$; namely, $g_i=g_i$ for all subscripts $i$. Hence $(G,\circ)$ is finitely generated.